# How to interpret negative binomial estimates with quadratic parametrization? (nbinom2(link="log")

Tags: r, interpretation, biostatistics, glmmtmb

I have a model where I use a negative binomial distribution with quadratic parametrization. I want to test whether some environmental variables affect the number (count) of a bird species:

```
  glmmTMB(Nbirds ~ Jul_DateSc + MoonSc + WindSpeedSc + NmothSc + 
     DistanceFromCityCenterSc + RainSc + (1|location), 
     data=BirdsData, family=nbinom2(link = "log"))
```

This is the output I got:

```
Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Location (Intercept) 0.431    0.657   
Number of obs: 197, groups:  Location, 14

Dispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 0.976 

Conditional model:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value             Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          4.9503957  0.3740343   13.24 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Jul_DateSc           0.0040427  0.0073414    0.55              0.58186    
MoonSc               1.5121981  0.5280343    2.86              0.00419 ** 
WindSpeedSc          0.0038701  0.0502247    0.08              0.93858    
NmothsSc             0.0103083  0.0024870    4.14            0.0000340 ***
```

where:
Nmoths is the number of moths (count)
Moon is the moon illuminance (%)
Jul_date is the Julian date, continuous, from 1 on...

Could anyone help me interpreting these results in terms of estimates? Is it correct to use incidence ratios?

Comment: I tried to make your model more readable. There wasn't a function specified in your original question. I assume from the tag that the function was supposed to be `glmmTMB`. Please correct if I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your outcome values are counts, so it's not clear what you mean by "incidence ratios" here.

These coefficients are interpreted as in any generalized linear model, in which a "[link function provides the relationship between the linear predictor and the mean of the distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function)" of outcome values. The link function for negative binomial in `glmmTMB` is the log. Thus the intercept is the log of the mean count when all the predictors have values of 0. As your model has no interaction terms, each regression coefficient represents the change in the log of the number of counts per unit increase of the corresponding predictor.

Comment: When I plot my data with the function plot_model, I get a graph with IRR (Incidence Rate ratios) instead of models' estimates, and I would like to show the estimates of my model. While models interpretation is still tricky as my predictors are scaled, still it make it easier to compare the predictors with each other... I tried the function Transform = F, but it did not work...

Comment: @Parusmajor that seems to be an issue with how the [`sjPlot` package's](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjPlot) `plot_model()` function handles objects from `glmmTMB`. Such software-specific questions are off-topic on this site, and I don't have any experience with that combination of software. Links on [this page](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/28500) might help.